# Ubuntu can´t find file

Tags: 20.04, scripts

I have a software called rosetta, which is suite for macromolecular modelling.

When trying to execute some a script:

```
home/roy/Rosetta/main/source/bin/rosetta_script.linuxccgrelease @flags
```

It says:

```
Couldn´t find file or directory
```

Why is that? I know for a fact that script is there, as I´ve literally copy it in the terminal

Comment: You're missing a `/` at the beginning of the path.

Comment: What is that `@flags` ? Could you edit your question and copy-paste the whole in- and output?